# Codeigniter ignores the middle segment from multiple segments

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri

I tried many ways to solve this problem but none works.

suppose I have a class:

```
class MyTestClass{
    function testPrint($a = '', $b = '', $c = '') 
    {
        echo '1: ' . $a . ', 2: ' . $b . ', 3: ' . $c;        
    }
}
```

and if I access this function by using this url
`http://localhost/ci/index.php/myTestClass/testPrint/a/b/c` you will see `1: a, 2: b, 3: c` as output, it's fine.

But if I assign $b to an empty string, the url will change to `http://localhost/ci/index.php/myTestClass/testPrint/a//c`

The output will change to `1: a, 2: c, 3:` It seems CI ignores the missing parameter.

**Question is how to prevent CI ignoring the missing parameter in the middle of uri?**

My expected output for just now the url is `1: a, 2: , 3: c`

Btw, I tried to use `$this->uri->segment(n)` to secure the parameter position, but it doesn't work.

I tried to update the routes.php by adding:

`$route['myTestClass/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "myTestClass/$1/$2/$3/$4";` but this does not change anything.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a CI issue, I would guess browser and/or webserver. If I enter the URL http://stackoverflow.com//questions//11310801//codeigniter-ignores-the-middle-segment-from-multiple-segments I will see this page. So likely what CI "sees" is `http://localhost/ci/index.php/myTestClass/testPrint/a/c`

Comment: When generating the URL, could you not set a default for `$b` (or other missing params), say 0 or the word `null`? Routes make the most sense, but there are to many cases to cater for!

Comment: @cchana It's not a problem with CI, its how your browser interprets the links. You may want to consider fixing the code to something like a/0/c, that what you have some type of input for "b". You can perform an if statement for `if ($b == 0) $b = '';` if you really need it to be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible in your case, but what I would do is use a short dummy string (xyz in this example) just to prevent having to deal with `/ /` and then filtering it out.

`http://localhost/ci/index.php/myTestClass/testPrint/a/xyz/c`

```
if ($b == 'xyz')
{ 
   $b = ''
}
```

If it's possible, try POST-ing variables instead of using the URI segments. That would make things a lot easier.
Hope this helps.

Update:

Since you can't POST, how about [enabling query strings](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)?

Comment: Thank you. But this will not work if the `xyz` is a user input value:)  Actually the url is called by a mobile devices, not by web page, that's why I can not use POST.

Comment: Hmmm, enable query strings is new to me,let me try first. Thanks:)